# How do i ajaxify /Use ajax on Side bar custom menues so that links are loaded to my content div without refreshing page

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

I have a vertical menu on My site ,I want to use ajax to load the Menu link into the content so the page doesnt have to reload,Please how can i go about it ,I tried the ajaxify module it doesnt seem to work properly.

Comment: Can you specify the Drupal version?

Comment: Am running Drupal 7.43  @JimmyKo

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ajax_pages`](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_pages) module.

> **Features**
>
> - Works inobtrusively out of the box
> - Requires only minimal theme modifications
> - Browser address bar updating using HTML5's history.pushState()
> - Full page reloading (page_top, page and page_bottom regions)
> - Transparently ajaxifies forms, including GET ones Handles redirects
> - Loads additional CSS and JS files as required
> - JS/CSS preprocessors and aggregation friendly
> - Ajax requests are GET and fully cacheable (also with Boost!)

Comment: THanks alot,I tried it but it seems to load the whole page as against loading only the node

Comment: @ksaj How about https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api ?

Comment: for some reason it seems doesnt seem to work well with my site,although it works well on another i tested on my local machine,I mean AJAX_Links _API .I decided to go with JQUERY_Ajax_load module .Its cool with some little animated feature.@Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

TO add ajax reload feature to a side bars;Menu Bars
*Download Jquery Ajax_load Module
*Install it from your module page
*Click the configuration button just to the right of the module after installing (Within the module page)
*Enter the target,Ajax call back
*Go to content type ,and choose the content type basic page,click manage display
*Choose jquery display
*Configure to your taste(I set the content to default so that the content can be visible while using the ajax feature)
Thats all
Test your link